Reusable workflow - GitHub Actions
I'm migrating from Jenkins to GitHub Actions.
Jenkins code:
    pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Start') {
            steps {
                sh 'ls'
            }
        }
        stage('Clone Repo') {
            steps {
                git credentialsId: 'githubapp', url: 'https://github..com/configurations.git', branch: 'dev'
            }
        }
        stage('Invoke_configure_cache_pipeline') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh 'cat cache.csv'
                    def csvFile = readFile(file: 'cache.csv')
                    csvFile.split('\n').each {String line->
                        final String names = sh(script:"echo $line", returnStdout: true).trim()
                        def repos = line.tokenize(",").toList()
                        build job: 'Configurations/configure_cache', parameters: [
                        string(name: 'cacheName', value: repos[0]), 
                        string(name: 'expirationType', value: repos[1]),
                        string(name: 'expirationTime', value: repos[2])
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('End') {
            steps {
                sh 'ls'
            }
        }
    }
}

GitHub Actions Code:
name: Bulk Test

on:
    workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: [Name]

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: List files (Start)
        run: |
            ls
            echo "*** List Files ***"

      - name: Clone configurations repository
        run: |
            echo "*** Clone configurations repository ***"
            git clone https://github.com/$userName/configurations.git
            git checkout dev
            git pull origin dev
            git branch

      - name: Setup Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '14'

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install node-fetch

      - name: Read CSV and trigger workflows
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        run: |
            const fs = require('fs');
            const fetch = require('node-fetch');

            async function triggerConfigureCacheWorkflow() {
              const owner = 'Rohit';
              const repo = 'config-pipeline-github-actions';
              const workflow_id = 'Config-Cache';
              const ref = 'dev';
              const token = process.env.GITHUB_TOKEN;

              const csvFile = fs.readFileSync('cache.csv', 'utf-8');
              const lines = csvFile.split('\n');

              for (const line of lines) {
                  const repos = line.split(',').map(item => item.trim());
                  const cacheName = repos[0];
                  const expirationType = repos[1];
                  const expirationTime = repos[2];

                  const response = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/repos/${owner}/${repo}/actions/workflows/${workflow_id}/dispatches`, {
                      method: 'POST',
                      headers: {
                          'Authorization': `token ${token}`,
                          'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3+json',
                          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                      },
                      body: JSON.stringify({
                          ref,
                          inputs: {
                              cacheName,
                              expirationType,
                              expirationTime
                          }
                      })
                  });

                  if (!response.ok) {
                      throw new Error(`Error triggering workflow: ${response.statusText}`);
                  }

                  console.log(`Workflow triggered successfully for cacheName: ${cacheName}`);
                }
            }

            triggerConfigureCacheWorkflow().catch(error => console.error(error));

      - name: List files (End)
        run: ls

Error: fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.vodafone.com': No such device or address
My code is in GitHub and the repository that I'm trying to clone is also in GitHub, do I really need to provide an user? I doubt my code has lot of flaws.
Goal: From Source workflow, I want to trigger destination workflow multiple times to configure cache.

The actions/checkout already clone the repo in the runner instance, therefore you don't need to add a git clone step afterwards. Just use cd <repo-name>, then you'll be able to access the repo files in the workflow.

Also note that the reusable workflow concept refers to something else in GitHub actions.

Code now fails at "Read CSV and trigger workflows"
I have slightly modified it now:
- name: Read CSV and trigger workflows         env:           GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}         run: |             #!/path/to/node             const fs = require("fs");             const fetch = require('node-fetch');
Error: /runner/_work/_temp/xxx: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('

It seems related to something else (involving Node). Could you open another question sharing more context (the whole workflow config for example)?

Looks like I have to wait. - "It's been 3 days since you asked your last question. We ask that you wait 1 days before asking again."
Although this community offers valuable insights, I have not found it to be welcoming.

I'll try again tomorrow. Thanks, @GuiFalourd!

Ok. For now, I'll add an official answer to this one.

The actions/checkout already clone the repository source code in the runner instance, therefore you don't need to add a git clone step afterwards.
Just use cd <repository-name>, then you'll be able to access the repo files in the workflow.
